# AutoLayOut - set UITableView height according to BannerView height

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout, adbannerview

I am using adBanner in my application which is at bottom of the screen and I am using tableview in my application.

I have established "Horizontal spacing" relation between adBannerView and tableview. Now my problem is before loading the advertisement in adBannerView I can see white space at the bottom of the screen but I want that my tableview cover that space before loading adBannerView and when adBannerView is loaded then my tableview should move up 50 pixels. How can I achieve this?

Any idea?

Comment: use constant property of constraints

Comment: Are You using autolayout in your application?

Comment: In autolayout you can't set frame of view programmatically.  I used hacks in my applications to adjust frame. I added two views one with full height and one with height - ad banner height. in Ad banner delegate methods i set frame of table view with required view e.g on ad load tableview frame = frame of view (height -ad banner view height) and before ad load set table view frame = full height view

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have adBanner of height 50 pixels. Set tableview's bottom space to adBanner 0 and don't set its height. Then set height for adBanner and create its constraint's property which should be initially 0 so your tableview will use that space initially. When adBannerView is loaded then set adBannerView height property 50, so tableview will automatically shift up. It may help

Answer (score 0):

Set Tablview's bottom space to supreview 0 with top space, leading space and trailing space constraint.
And modifiy ad banner delegate like this it will give required output.
IN viewDidLoad Adbanner view alpha = 0.0

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
NSLog(@"Ad Banner did load ad.");
CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGRect frame = self.viewForSource.frame;
frame.size.height = height-50;
self.viewForSource.frame = frame;
// Show the ad banner.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.adBanner.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

}

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"Unable to show ads. Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGRect frame = self.viewForSource.frame;
frame.size.height = height;
self.viewForSource.frame = frame;
// Hide the ad banner.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.adBanner.alpha = 0.0;

}];
```

}

Comment: Note take screen height if you will take tableview height it will minimise on each ad load . if you need demo app share your email id i will send you